# SQL Task Exporting query result to Excel missing rows

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I am trying to export my query result to an excel file. I did it successfully but when I look to the data instead of showing 12859 it only contains 104

EDIT 1: It only occurs when I added another column.

EDIT 2: Screenshots [image]

It should have

[image]

EDIT 3
 Its really weird coz I just found out something weird. The source type of `summary` column is `date`

[image]

Comment: any screenshots?

Comment: it basically missing datas.

Comment: we need to see how it looks like before and after

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I edited the post

Comment: how did you copy the result?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu via sql Task>import data

Comment: you can click on the black space between data and row 1 and copy all with headers and dump to excel. i think the import has a default limit

Comment: @maSTAShuFu but when I didnt included the `Summary` column it extract properly

Comment: what's the data in the summary column?

Comment: example data is `MAINGAY LINYA NI SUBS HINDI MARINIG` its generated by the user depends on the oucome of the call.

Comment: i might know the reason why... carriage return.. can you do replace(summarycolumn,char(10),'~')   or replace(summarycolumn,char(13),'~')

Comment: @maSTAShuFu i cant get you. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just go to Edit Mappings > Edit Sql > and change the data type to `LongText`